# How can I add wsse:Security to a Visual Studio generated web reference?

Tags: .net, web-services, visual-studio-2010, soap

I have used Visual Studio 2010 (wsdl.exe I believe is used for that) to generate a .NET 2.0 compatible web reference based on a WSDL (**not** a WCF client). When I use the proxy to call a service method I get this exception:

> An error was discovered processing the  header

In the exception details there is a code *InvalidSecurity*.

I have checked the documentation for the web service and it specifies the use of a wsse:Security element in the SOAP header.

```
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
  <wsse:UsernameToken>
    <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password>Password</wsse:Password>
  </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

I have tried the following code to add username and password before calling the method:

> service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Username", "Password");

But this doesn't help. Using Fiddler2 I see that the service call is never sent over the wire.

My question is: what can I do in my code to meet the requirements for calling the service with the wsse:Security elements?

Comment: how did you resolve this?

Comment: @n00b I don't remember, sorry.